# Errors getting XAMPP to work

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

First, I mistakenly downloaded MySQL workbench thinking it was the program I needed for my class- but I actually needed XAMPP. Because of this I had to change the port from 3306 to 3307 in XAMPP, and I assumed XAMPP would then work. It then tells me that my password was denied even though I never made one (phpMyAdmin access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)), So I thought maybe I had created one for workbench that somehow carried over and I forgot it, so I decided to uninstall the workbench package. Now I get these errors:

## 2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

— The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I've attempted to look up solutions but was unable to figure anything out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **Unfortunately, we can’t run your screenshot as code.**

Comment: MySQL Workbench is just a management tool for managing existing MySQL servers. It doesn't install any MySQL Server so you don't need to change the port in XAMPP because of that. If you have MySQL Workbench installed or not doesn't change anything.

Comment: MySQL Workbench is a tool to access MySQL servers so it does not need any specific blocked port like the MySQL default 3306. First of all, set your DB server back to use 3306. Make sure that the MySQL server is up and running and if applicable there is a firewall rule granting access to the port.